# Characterization of real functions which have limit at each point

Tags: real-analysis

The following problem is [Exercise 7.K](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA45) from the book van Rooij-Schikhof: A Second Course on Real Functions and it is very close to a question which was recently discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5176036#5176036).

So I thought that sharing this interesting problem with other MSE users could be useful. Here's the problem:

> Let $L$ be the set of all functions $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ that have the property that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists for all $a \in [0, 1]$.
>   Show that:
>   (i) $L$ is a vector space. Each $f \in L$ is bounded.
>   (ii) For each $f \in L$, define $f^c(x): = \lim\limits_{y\to x} f(y)$ ($x \in [0, 1]$). $f^c$ is continuous.
>   (iii) '$f^c =0$' is equivalent to 'there exist $x_1, x_2, \dots$ in $[0,1]$ and $a_1, a_2,\dots$ in $U$ with
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, such that $f(x_n) = a_n$ for every $n$, and $f=0$ elsewhere'.
>   (iv) Describe the general form of an element of $L$. Show that every $f\in L$ is Riemann integrable.

The original question in the chat was about functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, but it does not change much in the parts (iii) and (iv).

Comment: "$\lim f(x) $ exists for all $a$" is the same as saying that $f$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @MattN. No. For example $f=\chi_{\{0\}}$. Continuity would be: Limit exists at each point and it is equal to the value of the function: $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: Martin, I do not understand your $\chi_{(0)}$ example. What about the sequence $a_n=0$ if $n$ is even and $a_n=1/n$ otherwise? This _is_ a sequence converging to $0$, is'nt it?

Comment: @Thomas [Limit of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_the_real_line) at a point $a$ is defined using [punctured neighborhoods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctured_neighborhood#Punctured_neighbourhood) of this point. Or, if you want sequential definition, you have to take sequences which does not contain the value $a$ as one of their terms.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks (especially for your second comment to Thomas). Bottom-line (yet again): "Know your definitions." (<- talking to myself)

Comment: @Martin: but if you use punctured neighborhood, what about the function $f(x) = 1/x$ for $x>0$, and $f(0) = 0$? Are the limits also required to be finite?

Comment: Also, I wonder if the following characterization is right: "$f$ belongs to $L$ if and only if there exist a compact set $K \subset [0,1]$ and continuous functions $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h: K \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h = 0$ on $K'$ and $f = g+h$".

Comment: @D.Thomine You are right that if we allow the limit to be $\pm\infty$, we get also some unbounded functions. But most of the rest should remain the same, since $[-\infty,\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.\\ I am not sure I understand your second comment. What do you denote by $K'$. Derived set (limit points)? Complement?

Comment: In my precedent comment, $K'$ is the derived set.

Comment: @D.Thomine The set $K=\{0\}\cup\{1/n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ is compact and $K'=\{0\}$. The function defined by $f(x)=1$ for $x\in\{1/n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise fulfills $f|_{K'}=0$, but it does not have limit at $0$. I don't know about the other implication.

Comment: @Martin: This function is not continuous on $K$.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980022/a-function-having-limit-at-every-point-but-continuous-nowhere

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my solution, too.

---

(i) It is obvious that $L$ is a vector space.

If we fix some $\varepsilon>0$ then we have for each $a\in[0,1]$ an open neighborhood $U_a$ such that $\operatorname{diam} U_a<\varepsilon$. The sets $U_a$ form an open cover of the compact set $[0,1]$, so we have a finite subcover. Therefore the range of $f$ is covered by finitely many bounded sets and it is bounded itself.

---

(ii) Let us try to show the continuity of the function $f^c$ defined by $f^c(x)=\lim\limits_{y\to x} f(y)$.

Suppose that $f^c$ is not continuous at some point $a$. Let us denote $b:=f^c(a)$. Then there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to a$, $x_n\ne a$ and $f^c(x_n)$ does not converge to $b$.

By definition of $f^c$ we can find for each $x_n$ a point $y_n$ such that $|y_n-x_n|<1/2^n$ and $|f(y_n)-g(x_n)|<1/2^n$. We can assume that, in addition to this, $y_n\ne a$.

For such sequence we have $y_n\to a$ and $f(y_n)\not\to b=f^c(a)$, which contradicts the definition of $f^c$.

---

(iii) We want to show $f^c=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ has the form described in the part (iii).

The implication $\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ is easy: We have $f^c(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ for any sequence $x_n\to x$, $x_n\ne x$. If we choose any $\varepsilon$, there are only finitely many $n$'s such that $|f(x_n)|>\varepsilon$. This implies that the limit must be zero.

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ If suffices to show that the set $M_\varepsilon:=\{x\in\mathbb R; |f(x)|>\varepsilon\}$ is finite for each $\varepsilon>0$. (Once we have shown this, we can get all non-zero points as the union $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty M_{1/n}$, so there is only countably many of them. And they can also be ordered in the required way.)

Suppose that for some $\varepsilon>0$ the set $M_\varepsilon:=\{x\in\mathbb R; |f(x)|>\varepsilon\}$ is infinite. Then this set has an accumulation point $a\in[0,1]$. We have $|f_c(a)|\ge\varepsilon$, contradicting the assumption that $f^c$ is zero.

---

(iv) Now let $f$ be an arbitrary function from $L$.

It is relatively easy to see that if we denote $g:=f-f^c$, then $g^c$ is identically zero. (I.e., $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)=0$ for each $a\in[0,1]$.) Note that $f=f^c+g$.

So we get that each function from $L$ is a sum of a continuous function and a function which has the form described in the part (iii) of this exercise.

Now to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable we could use [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integrability_condition) and the fact that every countable set has Lebesgue measure zero.

But this can be also shown directly from the definition: For any given $\varepsilon>0$ we have only finitely many points such that $|f(x)|\ge\varepsilon$. If we cover them with small enough intervals, we will get that the Riemann sum over these intervals is in absolute value at most $\varepsilon$. For arbitrary partition containing the small intervals, the absolute value of the Riemann sum over the remaining intervals is at most $\varepsilon$. So we have $|R(f,\Delta)|\le 2\varepsilon$ whenever the norm of the partition is chosen small enough to ensure that the intervals around the "exceptional" points (the points with $|f(x)|\ge\varepsilon$) are small enough.

Comment: One can also show the set of discontinuities is countable. See one of my last questions.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I guess you mean this question: [Is this proof that $\Delta$ is countable correct?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240843/is-this-proof-that-delta-is-countable-correct)

Comment: Yes, I mean that one. By the way, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\dts{\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp}}$
First, we extend the domain $[0\dts1]$ into $\Bbb R$, say, $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ whenever $x_0<0$, and $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ whenever $x_0>1$, hence we can conclude that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists for each real number $a$. Just like the notation in (ii), and for ease, let $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x}f(x)$, so $f^c(x)=g(x)$ on the interval $[0\dts1]$.

Next, we can say that $f$ is bounded.

By definition of limit of function, there exists $\delta_\epsilon(a)>0$ such that $|f(x)-g(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_\epsilon(a)$, therefore $|f(x)|\le\max(|f(a)|,|g(a)|+\epsilon)=M_\epsilon(a)$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta_\epsilon(a)$.

Supposing that $\epsilon$ is a fixed positive real number, say $1$, and let $\Sigma$ is the set of open intervals $I(x)=(x-\delta_\epsilon(x)\dts x+\delta_\epsilon(x))$, where $0\le x\le1$. We have $\Sigma_\epsilon$ covers the closed set $[0\dts1]$, thus there exists finite subset of $\Sigma_\epsilon$, say $\Sigma_\epsilon^*$, which covers the closed set $[0\dts1]$, and let $\Sigma_\epsilon^*=\{I_\epsilon(a_1),\ldots,I_\epsilon(a_m)\}$, we have $|f(x)|\le M_\epsilon(a_k)$ on the open interval $I_\epsilon(a_k)$, so $f$ is bounded.

Now, let's prove that $g$ is continuous. For all $\epsilon>0$, we have $|f(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$ where $x$ is an arbitrary point on the open interval $I_\epsilon(x_0)$. Let $y\in I_\epsilon(x_0)$, and let $x$ tends to $y$ but not equals $y$, we have $f(x)\to g(y)$, therefore $|g(y)-g(x_0)|\le\epsilon$, hence $g$ is continuous.

Then, supposing that $f^c(x)=0$ on the interval $[0\dts1]$, we have $g(x)=0$ for arbitrary real number $x$. For all $\epsilon>0$, we should remember that there's a corresponding finite cover $\Sigma_\epsilon^*$ of closed set $[0\dts1]$, and $\Sigma_\epsilon^*=\{I_\epsilon(a_1),\ldots,I_\epsilon(a_m)\}$. Now let's analyse this result closely. For $x\in I_\epsilon(a_k)$, and $x\neq a_k$, we have $|f(x)|=|f(x)-g(a_k)|<\epsilon$, so $|f(x)|\ge\epsilon\,\Longrightarrow\,x=a_k\textrm{ for some }k$. Thus we can sort all $x$ such that $f(x)\neq0$ in decreasing order of $|f(x)|$, and arrange them in a sequence.

Finally, we should prove that, if we can arrange all non-zero points on interval $[0\dts1]$ in a sequence $S$ such that the value converges to $0$, we have $f^c=0$. For any point $y$ in $[0\dts1]$ and arbitrary positive real number $\epsilon$, there's only finity many points in $S$ whose absolute value $\ge\epsilon$, thus $f(x)<\epsilon$ holds on some neighborhood of $y$ (if $y=0,1$, it's one sided neighborhood), so $f^c(y)=0$.