# Is there a function having a limit at every point while being nowhere continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Is there a function $\,f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,$ which has a limit at every $x\in\mathbb R$ and is everywhere discontinuous?

Comment: It's a question from a graduate exam.

Comment: Yeah this looks like a standard general exam question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164946/characterization-of-real-functions-which-have-limit-at-each-point

Answer (score 35):

**Answer.** No.

Instead, the following is true: *If a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has a limit for every $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ is discontinuous in a set of points which is at most countable.*

More specifically, we have the following facts:

**Fact A.** *If $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$, then $g$ is continuous everywhere.*

**Fact B.** *The set $A=\{x: f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is countable.*

**Fact C.** *The function $\,f\,$ is continuous at $\,x=x_0\,$ if and only if $\,f(x_0)=g(x_0)$, and hence $f$ is discontinuous in at most countably many points.*

For Fact A, let $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
0<\lvert y-x\rvert<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad  g(x)-\varepsilon<f(y)<g(x)+\varepsilon,
$$
but the above inequality implies that for every $z$, with $|z-x|<\delta$,
$$
g(x)-\varepsilon \le g(z)=\lim_{y\to z}f(y) \le g(x)+\varepsilon,
$$
and hence $g$ is continuous.

For Fact B, define for $\varepsilon>0$ the set
$$A_\varepsilon=\{x: \lvert\,f(x)- g(x)\rvert>\varepsilon\}.$$ This set cannot have a limit point, for otherwise, $f$ would not have a limit there. Thus $A_\varepsilon$ is at most countable. Next observe that
$$
A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_{1/n},
$$
and hence $A$, the set of discontinuities of $f$, is at most countable.

Fact C is straight-forward.

Comment: what a great answer! :)

Comment: One wonders what happens if one has a model of set theory such that  "a countable union of a countable sets is countable" is false.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and great response!

Comment: Actually, the proof of this requires the Axiom of Choice, and hence your question is indeed plausible.

Comment: It doesn't require AC in full; much weaker forms of choice, which you can't do much analysis without, will do.

Comment: Since those sets are discrete subsets of a [second-countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), they can be given canonical enumerations. $\:$ (Take a countable basis, and enumerate each set according to the first basic subset whose intersection with the discrete set in exactly the given element.) $\:$ Thus the Axiom of Choice is not needed for the OP. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Actually, what Ricky Demer says is correct. For each of the sets $A_{1/n}$ we can obtain an injection $f_n: A_{1/n}\to\mathbb Z$, without the Axiom of Choice.