# Is a function with limits Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose
$f
:
[
0, 1
]
→
\mathbb{R}$
and
$\lim\limits_{x
\rightarrow
c}
f
(
x
)$
exists for all
$c
\in
[
a
,
b
]$. Show that $f$
is Riemann integrable on
$[
a
,
b
]$.

I can show this $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ since the limit exists at every point. But I'm not sure how to proceed. Any hints or help would be great.

Comment: You should replace $[a,b]$ with $[-1,1]$ or vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

Show that such $f$ with a limit that exists on every point of interval $[a,b]$ is discontinuous in an at most countable set (it is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/980047/587142) on this site). The main idea is showing that the set $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$, where $g(y) = \lim_{y \rightarrow x} f(y)$, is at most countable.

Then, apply the Lebesgue criterion to show that the function is integrable since countable sets have measure zero.

Comment: The question asks for Riemann integrability, so the Lebesgue criterion doesn't apply.

Comment: @TonyK, the Lebesgue criterion is for Riemann integrability. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral middle of page.

Comment: You are right, of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of a more elementary approach: Let $\epsilon > 0.$ For every $x\in [0,1]$ there is an interval $I_x$ centered at $x$ where

$$\sup_{I\setminus \{x\}} f - \inf_{I\setminus \{x\}}< \epsilon/2.$$

The reason we need to remove $x$ from $I_x$ is because $\lim_{\,t\to x} f(t)$ pays no attention to the value of $f$ at $x.$

Because $[0,1]$ is compact, finitely many of these intervals cover $[0,1].$ Let's label them $I_{x_k},$ $k=1,2,\dots n.$ The $x_k$ form a partition of $[0,1],$ but we need to tweak this partition because the values of the $f(x_k)$ could be a bit wild. However, as you noted, $|f|$ is bounded by some $M.$ So for each $k$ we can choose $y_k<x_k<z_k$ very close to $x_k$ and then let $P$ be the partition formed by throwing in all the $x_k,y_k,z_k.$ For this partition, we will have

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon,$$

which implies $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why we need to omit $x \in I$. I used a similar argument to prove $f$ is not bounded, but I did not omit  $x$. Also, I'm not quite sure where your first inequality came from @zhw.

Comment: It's possible for $f$ to have limit $0$ at $x$ while $f(x)=10.$ In other words, the value $f(x)$ is irrelevant in the limit process. In my first inequality, I am using the fact that the limit exists at $x.$ All values in $I_x\setminus \{0\}$ are close to the limit, hence close to each other.

Comment: I see, thank you. Now I am stuck on $\sup f(x) - \inf f(x) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ in $[y_k, x_k]$ or $[x_k,z_k]$. How does $f$ being bounded and  $y_k$ and $z_k$ being very close to $x_k$ help? @zhw.

Comment: Also, when you say all values in $I_x \setminus \{x\}$ are close to the limit, do you mean all $f(y)$ for $y \in I_x \setminus \{x\}$ are close to the limit? @zhw.

Comment: For the first question, note that $\inf (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)=L-\epsilon $,$\sup (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)=L+\epsilon .$ So $\sup - \inf = 2\epsilon.$ Yes on the second question.