# If $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ limit exists at every point $c\in[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Berkeley problems problem 1.5.4

> Suppose $f$ is real valued function of one real variable such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ exists for all $c\in [a,b]$. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Consider a jump discontinuity $c$. There exists a neighborhood s.t. image of a given point in this neighborhood is *close* to $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$. So while calculating $U(P, f)$ and $L(P, f)$, the actual value of $f(c)$ may be ignored. But how to justify this?

One way is to consider a partition $P$ which contains $c_1$ and $c_2$ situated *close* to $c$ and on either side of $c$.

Please give a hint. Please do not give solution. Thanks!

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists for all $c \in [a,b]$ it means that $f$ is continuous, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Gabrielek it requires ${\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=f(c)}$, which is not implied by the limit simply existing

Comment: It doesn't imply $f$ is continuous, since it could have point discontinuities.

Comment: Ops, I assumed it was $f(c)$, my fault

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119713/is-a-function-with-limits-riemann-integrable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:For each $c \in [a,b]$, the hypothesis can be used to show that there exits a $\delta_c >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ if $x,y \in (c-\delta_c,c+\delta_c) \setminus\{c\}$. The intervals of the form $I_c = (c-\delta_c,c+\delta_c)$ form an open cover for $[a,b]$. Using compactness, finitely many of them say $(c_1-\delta_{c_1},c_1+\delta_{c_1}),\dots,(c_n-\delta_{c_n},c_n+\delta_{c_n})$ cover $[a,b]$. Now choose a partition with $x_0 = a,x_1 = c_1,\dots,x_{n-1} = c_n,x_n = b$.