# Is there a function that's discontinuous everywhere but has a limit everywhere?

Tags: limits, continuity

Does there exist a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit of the function at every real number $x$ exists as a real number, but such that the value of the function at every real number $x$ is always different from the limit?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980022/is-there-a-function-having-a-limit-at-every-point-while-being-nowhere-continuous).