Limits and monotonicity to find function
Given functions $f, g: \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $f(x)$ is monotonic and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=g(a)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb R $. How can I show that if $g$ is continuous at some $k \in \mathbb R$, then $f(k)=g(k)$? The previous example I did was $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x)=g(a)$ and I proved $f(x)=g(x)$ by considering $f(x-\epsilon)$ and $f(x+\epsilon)$ and using monotonicity, but now I don’t know how to solve with only $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=g(a)$(and similarly when only $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x)=g(a)$).

Apologies, I wasn't clear enough. The first equality is true for all real $a$

See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/980047/72031

By definition of $g(k) $ we have for every $\epsilon>0$ a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that $$g(k) - \epsilon<f(y) <g(k) +\epsilon$$ whenever $k<y<k+\delta$. Now choose any specific point $x\in(k, k+\delta) $ and taking limits of the above inequality as $y\to x^+$ we get $$g(k) - \epsilon\leq g(x) \leq g(k) +\epsilon$$ And thus $\lim_{x\to k^+} g(x) = g(k) $ so that $g$ is continuous from right at every point.
Further since $f$ is increasing we have $f(k) \leq \lim_{x\to k^+} f(x) =g(k) $. Suppose that $f(k) < g(k) $ and $\epsilon=g(k) - f(k)>0$. Then for all $y<k$ we have $f(y) \leq f(k) =g(k) - \epsilon$. Taking limits as $y\to x^+$ for some $x<k$ we get $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x^+} f(y) \leq g(k) - \epsilon$. Since this holds for all $x<k$ it follows that $g$ is discontinuous from left at $k$. By contrapositive we see that if $g$ is continuous at $k$ then we must have $f(k) =g(k) $.
